# How to write a cups raster driver which is writing to a specific device

Tags: linux, printing, driver, kernel-module, cups

For a embedded linux project i wrote a printer driver for a custom thermal printer. Everything worked fine. I have a device /dev/thprint now and i can just write pixel into this device and its actually printing this pixels (just a bit array with a fixed with of 384 pixels). 
The next step is now to make a cups raster driver, so i can use it as "real" printer. I looked up many examples but i just don't understand where to specify which device to use. 
Does anybody have an example how to do this ?

Comment: This is unrelated to your question, but would you share with me the printer driver source code?